# HEAD with WebClient?

Tags: .net, http, webclient, head

I am going to assume the answer is no but....
Is there a way to use WebClient to send the HEAD method and return the headers as a string or something similar?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are right WebClient does not support this. You can use HttpWebRequest and set the method to HEAD if you want this functionality:

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "HEAD";
request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 18):

Another way is to inherit from WebClient and override [GetWebRequest(Uri address)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest.aspx).

```
    public class ExWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public string Method
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Method))
                webRequest.Method = Method;

            return webRequest;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For a newbie, how do I call this overridden class?

Comment: `var wc = new ExWebClient();` instead of `var wc = new WebClient();`

Comment: @bendecko because the access modifier is protected you can't call it from outside the class. However you can just create a facade method to call the protected method worst case. Ex: public WebRequest GetWebRequest2(Uri address) { return GetWebRequest(uri); } //Use a better name than GetWebRequest2 please

Answer (score 4):

Most web servers that I request from will accept this method.  Not every web server does though.  IIS6, for example, will honor the request method SOMETIMES.

This is the status code that is returned when a method isn't allowed...

```
catch (WebException webException)
            {
                    if (webException.Response != null)
                    {
                        //some webservers don't allow the HEAD method...
                        if (((HttpWebResponse) webException.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed)
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: This does not answer the question as to whether WebClient supports  sending a HEAD request.