# How to get content type of a web address?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, content-type

I want to get type of a web address. For example [this](http://feed.2barnamenevis.com/2barnamenevis) is a Html page and its page type is `text/html` but the type of [this](http://feed.2barnamenevis.com/2barnamenevis?format=xml) is `text/xml`. [this](http://bayanbox.ir/user/ahmadalli/images/div.png) page's type seems to be `image/png` but it's `text/html`.

**I want to know how can I detect the content type of a web address like [this](http://bayanbox.ir/user/ahmadalli/images/div.png)?**

Comment: Not about it should be.  A URL has a content type in the header or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it should be something like this

```
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com") as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request != null)
    {
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        string contentType = "";

        if (response != null)
            contentType = response.ContentType;
    }
```

Comment: I also used your code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11996430/1003464) thanks.

Comment: `request.Method = "HEAD";` may also be added for speed.

Comment: `if (response != null) contentType = response.ContentType;` can be shorted to `contentType = response?.ContentType;` ([info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28352116/11585798))

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Response header: `content-type`

For a more detailed response, please provide a more detailed question.

Comment: OP asked how to get that information in C#, not what the header is.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the `Content-Type` by the Http header of the response,for http://bayanbox.ir/user/ahmadalli/images/div.png ,the header is

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 14 Aug 2012 03:01:41 GMT
Server:bws
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (MyClient client = new MyClient())
    {
        client.HeadOnly = true;
        string uri = "http://www.google.com";
        byte[] body = client.DownloadData(uri); // note should be 0-length
        string type = client.ResponseHeaders["content-type"];
        client.HeadOnly = false;
        // check 'tis not binary... we'll use text/, but could
        // check for text/html
        if (type.StartsWith(@"text/"))
        {
            string text = client.DownloadString(uri);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
```

Will get you the mime type from the headers without downloading the page. Just look for the content-type in the response headers.

Comment: Presumably `MyClient` is a subclass of `WebClient` with `HEAD` support?

Comment: Yes you are correct.  This was copied from another sample I worked on for checking for binary http responses.

Comment: it may be mre useful to readers if you link to that other sample :)

Comment: [WebClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268926/head-with-webclient) with **method** support -

Answer (score 1):

Read up on HTTP headers.

HTTP headers will tell you the content type. For example:

> content-type: application/xml.

There are two ways to determining the content-type

1. the file extension invoked by the URL
2. the http header content-type

The first one was somewhat promoted by microsoft during to old days and is not a good practice anymore.

If the client has display constraints accepting only certain content-type, it would request the server with the headers like

```
accept: application/json
accept: text/html
accept: application/xml
```

And then if the server could supply one of those and chooses XML it would return the content with the header

```
content-type: application/xml.
```

However, some services include further information like

```
content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

rather than using a header of its own for the character encoding.

Comment: OP asked how to get that information in C#, not what the header is.