# Angular http post formData unsupported media type from C# Controller

Tags: c#, angular, http, form-data

The (Angular) code I'm trying to execute looks like this:

```
   this.http.post(url, formData, httpOptions).subscribe(  
          (data) => { 
            console.log(data);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

The formData is simply:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('listNetworkConstituents', JSON.stringify(params));
```

Tried lots of options including:

```
   const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    }
```

I've validated params data and Json isn't having any trouble with it.
Fiddler confirms the request gets to the server and then is rejected:
"server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)"

I know use of FormData is working elsewhere against this server.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance. Yogi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

Above excerpt is from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Please compare the content-type and content-encoding in your header and make sure that the URL that is listening to this call is expecting the type you are sending.

**Things you can do**

- Go to the destination API/URL and look at its settings and see what format it accepts.
- Use Postman or another utility to make the same call and see if it goes through
- Compare the json body that you are sending and see if there is any issues

Comment: Jawad: this looks like good advice.  The server is currently running in Visual Studio - debug.  Do you happen to know how I might see the settings for content-encode and type?  Thanks again.

Comment: Tried the code here and it comes back with good info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11945256/1390548

Comment: Wow... so the code is probably okay.  then I need to focus on the server.