# Special chars not working with WebClient DownloadString using page's encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, webclient, downloadstring

**EDIT**: The characters come correctly, but in the middle of the page there's this line `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">`, afterwards the special characters become `é` as `&eacute;` (that are represented fine in browser), but are represented as `eacute;` (without the **&**) if downloaded via WebClient. **END EDIT**

I am extracting an excerpt from a web using WebClient + RegEx.

But setting the encoding correctly still makes `é` as `eacute;`, `ç`as `ccedil;`, `í` as `iacute;` etc.

I followed [DownloadString and Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953001/downloadstring-and-special-characters) example to correctly set the charset (`ISO-8859-1`):

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.DownloadString("https://myurl"); //
var contentType = wc.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"];
var charset = Regex.Match(contentType, "charset=([^;]+)").Groups[1].Value;
wc.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);
```

It does set `charset` like the document's (`ISO-8859-1`), but when i do the follow-up `DownloadString` (*i know i could set the encoding before and just do one `wc.DownloadString`, but i wanted to follolw the accepted answer's example*):

```
string result = wc.DownloadString("https://myurl");
```

The special characters still come wrong.

**NOTE**: I am using a non-English Windows 10 (if it's relevant)

**NOTE 2**: The page's special characters appear correctly in any browser

My question is, why the `WebClient` don't download correctly even with the correct charset set?

Comment: I expect this is not a problem of your client. Did you try the same in a different client? For example you can use some browser extensions to tailor web requests as you wish. What I want to say is that the web server maybe simply sends the data in this form.

Comment: WebClient.Encoding is used to convert unknown characters to unicode, which is .NET's internal form. But when your web server sends eacute;, it is just a standard text. None of its parts are unknown. It is regular e, regular a, regular c... What you probably want to get is something like HtmlDecode, which is something completely different than this Encoding stuff.

Comment: The page opens correctly in any browser, it is just when i access through WebClient that this happens. Perhaps i should add some headers to the WebClient (user-agent, accept, etc)? **EDIT**: Setting headers didn't work also.

Comment: I just looked better at the page source, there's this line `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">` in the middle of the document, afterwards special characters become like i said in my question (although it represents fine in browser), but with **&** (i.e `&ccedil;`).

Comment: I didn't mean open in browser. You must look at bare data, beacuse each browser processes those &eacute; and similar things, as it is normal valid representation of é etc. This is normal behavior: If page source contains &eacute;, it is sent in this form to browser and the browser must decode it itself to é. Your program must decode it manually too.

Answer (score -1):

using System.Text;

wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: The [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) will help you format your answer properly, but you really should add explanatory text to your code also.