# How can I measure the html size (KB) of a website with c#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to compute the size in KB or Bytes of my website's html. I know that there are several websites that can provide me this value, but I don't want to use them. I'd like to use my own code. Could you please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Most websites contain dynamic content so the size will not be fixed. If you want to minimize traffic use a [http HEAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268926/head-with-webclient) request instead. The size (if provided) will be in the header field `Content-Length`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the size of the HTML loaded initially by your browser, you can use [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) like below:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) 
{
   string s = client.DownloadString(url);
   // s contains the whole document text
   int strCount = s.Length;
   int byteCount = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(s);
}
```

However, keep in mind that the actually downloaded data may increase due to AJAX calls and dynamically created DOM elements (after document is ready).

Comment: And then he can get the acutal "size" by getting the byte count of the requested site... System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(s);

Comment: @oopbase - thanks for the constructive comment. I had missed the purpose of the question :).

Comment: Please at least use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`. `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode` works but looks wrong and doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way to do this would be to use WebRequest class and read the [ContentLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.WebResponse.ContentLength);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property without actually reading the content, to avoid unnecessary data download.

Also, as stated by @Manfred Radlwimmer, using HTTP HEAD would be a more efficient way.