# I need to use Async/Await in my already running program to make it faster

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I am having a program in VB, which searches for image in a website as follows:

www.website.com/1.jpg | www.website.com/2.jpg | www.website.com/3.jpg

in loop, and the program opens up only 3.jpg in browser, since 1 and 2 jpg does not exit in server. The program is up and running, but is very very slow, around 120 searches in a minute. However one of my colleagues designed the same program in Angular and that program is running very fast, around 500/600 searches in a minute.

He told me, what he did is generated 50 asynchronous calls to server, and then again 50, and then again 50 and went on like this. thus making his program very fast and ovbiously accurate.

I studied and learnt, that in Visual Basic too, we have async and wait calls to server request, but I cannot figure out how.

Here goes my existing code. Can anyone help me.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim MYURL as string
    itemsF = 0

    While Not itemsF = 50000
        MYURL = "www.website.com/" & itemsF & ".jpg"
        CheckPageExists(MYURL)
        itemsF=itemsF+1
    End While
End Sub

Private Function CheckPageExists(ByVal url As String) As Boolean    
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse

    request = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Timeout = 5000

    Try
        response = request.GetResponse()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'IMAGE DOES NOT EXITS
        Exit Function
    End Try

    Process.Start(url)
End Function
```

Comment: which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: yes but what version of the .NET framework are you using? Check [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231632/how-to-find-the-net-framework-version-of-a-visual-studio-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make `CheckPageExists` an `Async` method:

```
Private Async Function CheckPageExists(ByVal url As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Timeout = 5

    Dim Result As Boolean

    Try
        Using response As HttpWebResponse = Await request.GetResponseAsync.ConfigureAwait(False)
            Using responseReader As New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

                Dim actualResponse As String = Await responseReader.ReadToEndAsync
                Result = True

            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'IMAGE DOES NOT EXITS
        Result = False
    End Try

    Console.WriteLine(url)

    ''Process.Start("chrome.exe", url)
    Return Result
End Function
```

As you can see, instead of `GetResponse` we are using `GetResponseAsync`, which is `Async` itself. This method is very similar to what you were doing before, I 
just added `Return` statements for clarity and a `StreamReader` to read the response of your website.

Once you've done that, you just need to change your `Button2_Click` method to call this other method, which incorporates all you were doing before:

```
Async Function MakeRequests() As Task
    Dim tasks As List(Of Task(Of Boolean)) = New List(Of Task(Of Boolean))
    Dim itemsF As Integer = 5

    For i = 1 To itemsF
        Dim MYURL As String = "http://www.touchegolfschool.com/images/" & i & ".jpg"

        tasks.Add(CheckPageExists(MYURL))
    Next

    While tasks.Select(Function(x) x.Result).Count < tasks.Count
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    End While

End Function
```

The main change was adding `tasks.Select(Function(x) x.Result).Count < tasks.Count`; what you were seeing before was a request made but never returning because of the time it took to return; telling the main function to wait until all requests have a result makes the application wait long enough for the responses to come.

Here the main difference is the use of `Tasks`.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/making-asynchronous-requests) for official documentation on asynchronous programming.

Comment: i did all that...but the debugger goes to this line  Using response As Net.HttpWebResponse = Await request.GetResponseAsync and exits function.

Comment: nothing comes out even if the page exists on server

Comment: oh < i know. I already added original url to it...so dont worry on the URL.  But the program when it goes to CHECKPAGEEXITS function, it does not go beyond this line:

 Using response As HttpWebResponse = Await request.GetResponseAsync

..and exits

Comment: For example lets try this with http://www.touchegolfschool.com/images/5.jpg    and generate loop of 1 to 10.jpg, only 5jpg should be thrwn out in browser. you can check the program

Comment: I edited my code, putting the using statements inside the try-catch. are there any exceptions caught?

Comment: ALSO i removed "i" from tasks.Add(CheckPageExists(MYURL, i)) as "too many arguments to private function"

Comment: You are right, i edited my answer. I also tested it, it seems to work.

Comment: but it does not work for me...can u send me the solution file. roy [DOT] ranajoy  AT GMAIL

Comment: it does not get past "Using response As HttpWebResponse = Await request.GetResponseAsync" and exits back to MakeRequests loop

Comment: can u mail me your vb solution file?

Comment: inside the for look i added i=i+1 after...."tasks.Add(CheckPageExists(MYURL))", even that does not get executed, the program starts reading again from first line of loop with i=0, everytime, after skipping from request.GetResponseAsync

Comment: I'm not sure I'm allowed to email that, but please try now the updated code; if you want to uncomment the Process.Start line go ahead. Now it works, right?

Comment: The main change was adding `tasks.Select(Function(x) x.Result).Count < tasks.Count`; what you were seeing before was a request made but never returning because of the time it took to return; telling the main function to wait until all requests have a result makes the application wait long enough for the responses to come. I limited the example to 5 requests.

Comment: it works...just need to put Process.Start(url) inside TRY

Comment: glad to hear that; if you are satisfied by my solution, you can mark it as answer

Comment: i just upvoted it 1 point. how do i select this as an answer?

Comment: click on the check mark beside the answer [like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Comment: i did that. One more question. I read somewhere...
1) get_headers() actually uses GET requests, which are not needed if you just want to know if a file exists. Use HEAD instead

can we use it?

Comment: something like : request.Method = "HEAD"

Comment: I'm not sure but you may be right, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268926/head-with-webclient?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)